# Support for usb 3.0?

Tags: usb, hardware, drivers

I could not seem to find the question here but I was wondering what experience if any users have had with USB 3.0?

My asus p5x58d has usb 3 on it but I have yet to try it out and also do not know much in terms of support.

I feel this is best as a community wiki where we can share experience on USB 3.0.

[This article](http://www.linux.com/news/hardware/peripherals/278579-linux-and-usb-30) discussed briefly linux and usb 3.

Let the comments flow...

Comment: Why a -1 with no comment?  Is there something wrong about this post?

Comment: I am guessing it's because it's subjective? I'm not sure, I wasn't the downvoter.

Comment: I suppose, not quite sure how usb 3.0 support is a subjective subject.

Comment: It is likely because this is a site fore specific questions and answers. This item would be better as a forum topic somewhere.

Comment: @Shawn J. Goff.: Suggestion on where?  Did you mean another SE or something like a Linux forum?

Answer (score 3):

Do an `lspci` from a root prompt.  Do you see anything about "USB 3.0" host adapter in that list?  If so, you should enjoy the same support from USB 3.0 devices that Linux provides for USB 2.0 and USB 1.1, which ranges from "Works great!" to "I had to do a bunch of crazy stuff in `udev` to get this to do what I want" to "There's only Windows drivers for this!".

Comment: Its not about "explicit" support but more of is it worth for example paying for a usb 3.0 enclosure for external hard drive.  I am asking more "do the costs outweigh the benefits" for moving to USB 3.0 now or is it too soon.  Appreciate the insight though!

Comment: I would imagine Linux USB mass storage support would not be problematic with USB 3.0, as long as the controller shows up in `lspci`.  I'd say if you need the speedy access to your hard drive through USB then do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider esata or sas technologies which may be better than the USB3 and usb c formats for large file transfers.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, which appears to be very specifically about USB 3 and says nothing about file transfers.